# echoproperties task depending on log level

Tags: ant

Is there a chance to make the echoproperties task depend on the log level (something similar to the level parameter in echo task)? It would be helpful to have some echoproperties outputs only when ant runs in debug mode (-debug).

Alternative: how can I detect in Ant the current log level? Is there e a property that contains the log level?

Thx!
Frank

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462732/make-ant-quiet-without-the-q-flag) may help you. Just replace `setMessageOutputLevel` with `getMessageOutputLevel`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not `getMessageOutputLevel` getter, but just `msgOutputLevel` protected field: http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.7.0/org/apache/tools/ant/DefaultLogger.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ant [record](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html) task for this use case.

See [How do I capture the output of an antcall inside of ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851785/how-do-i-capture-the-output-of-an-antcall-inside-of-ant/).